# SwiftUI Chaining Animations

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to do something very simple. Animate padding first then animate width.

```
@state var animate = false

Rect().frame(width: animate ? 200 : 1, height: 2).animate(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.5)).padding(.bottom, animate ? 300 : 10).animate(.easeOut)
```

From this code I expect the padding to be using the outermost animation modifier and the frame using the inner one. So I expect padding to animate first then frame to animate with a delay but they both are animating with the outermost animation.

What am I dont wrong?

Update: Working solution with Asperi's method of async after

```
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 0.1
    @State private var isFirstResponder = false

    private var becameFirstResponder: Binding<Bool> { Binding (
        get: { self.isFirstResponder },
        set: {
            self.isFirstResponder = $0
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                self.width = self.isFirstResponder ? 240 : 0.1

            }

            }
        )}

    var body: some View {
       Divider().frame(width: width, height: 2)
.animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 1), value: width)
.background(Color.primary)
.padding(.bottom, keyboard.height).animate(.easeOut)
   }
```

As you can see this code is too complex for a very simple chained animation. Anyone got a solution without using asyncAfter?

Answer (score 1):

You delay animation but change both values at once, that's why it is confused.

Here is possible solution

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoDelayedAnimations: View {
    @State private var animate = false

    // separate animatable values
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var padding: CGFloat = 10
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: width, height: 2)
                    .animation(.easeOut, value: width) // explicit to width
                .padding(.bottom, padding)
                    .animation(.easeOut, value: padding) // explicit to padding
            Divider()
            Button("Go") {
                self.padding = self.padding == 10 ? 300 : 10

                // delay value change, not animation (it reacts on change)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    self.width = self.width == 1 ? 200 : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it only works when using asyncAfter? Any idea why? I am using a binding to set the width so to make it work I had to create a custom binding and call asyncAfter on the setter of that custom binding with a delay. But this seems like a very messy solution to a very simple problem of having two animations set by bindings with a delay? or is it one of those SwiftUI simple requirements gone too complex gottyas?